# Vuetify validation message variable

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, vuetify.js, translation

I want to offer my website in two different languages. I use vuetify for form validation. The problem is, I don't know how to put the "Rule-Text" into a variable. Can everybody help.

I have the following setup:

```
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation @submit.prevent="submit">
   <v-text-field class="mt-5"
     v-model="id"
     color= "orange"
     label="Enter ID"
     :rules="IdRule"
     counter
     maxlength="30"
     required
     clearable
     outlined
     v-on:keyup.enter="comp"
   ></v-text-field>
</v-form>

...
    
IdRule: [
  v => !!v || 'ID is required',
  v => /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/.test(v) || 'Only letters and numbers allowed, no special characters',
],
```

How can I put the two stings 'ID is required' and 'Only letters and numbers allowed, no special characters' into variables so when the user changes the language also the language of these strings will change.

Thanks a lot!

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a variable for the text. And use the language according to your need. Here is my idea in the demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      email: '',
      languages: ['english', 'bangla'],
      language: 'english',
      rulesText: {
        bangla: {
          minLen: 'অন্তত ২০',
          required: 'প্রয়োজন'
        },
        english: {
          minLen: 'At least 20',
          required: 'Required'
        }
      },
      rules: {
        required: value => !!value || this.rulesText[this.language].required,
        counter: value => value.length >= 20 || this.rulesText[this.language].minLen,
      },
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.18/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.18/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
            <v-select :items="languages" v-model="language"></v-select>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
            <v-text-field v-model="title" :rules="[rules.required, rules.counter]" label="Title" counter maxlength="20"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>


        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```